# Setting discriminator value dynamically (Hibernate mappings)

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hibernate-mapping, discriminator

I have a scenario something like this

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TANDC_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 32)
@Table(name = "T_TERMS_AND_CONDITIONS", schema = DataSourceConfig.PERSISTENCE_SCHEMA_NAME)
public class TermsAndConditions {
...
}
```

And it's child class having the discriminator value "CREATOR"

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CREATOR")
public class AccountTermsAndConditions extends TermsAndConditions {
...
}
```

Another child class having the discriminator value "ORDER"

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("ORDER")
public class OrderTermsAndConditions extends TermsAndConditions {
...
}
```

Here, my requirement is to facilitate the Terms and Conditions mapping for a new type of account called the "USER" which is related to my `AccountTermsAndConditions`.

Now, I don't want to add one more class for the account type "USER" (something like `UserTermsAndConditon`) as both the "CREATOR" and "USER" are related to types of Accounts.

I need a possible solution here to set my discriminator value to either 'CREATOR' or 'USER' based on the type of account.

Is there any way to set my discriminator value inside the class based on conditions?

I have also seen the oracle's documentation which states:

> "If the DiscriminatorValue annotation is not specified and a
>   discriminator column is used, a provider-specific function will be
>   used to generate a value representing the entity type."

How do I proceed with the implementation?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It appears what you may want to leverage is the `@DiscriminatorFormula` since you're using single table inheritance.  With this, we can map both `CREATOR` and `USER` types to `CREATOR` so that the same java class type is reused.

```
@DiscriminatorFormula(
  "case when TANDC_TYPE = 'ORDER' then 'ORDER' " +
  "else ( " +
  "  case when TANDC_TYPE in ('CREATOR','USER') then 'CREATOR' " +
  "  else 'Unknown' " +
  "  end ) " +
  "end "
 )
```

I would probably suggest changing `AccountTermsAndConditions` discriminator to `ACCOUNT` and then map `CREATOR` and `USER` to `ACCOUNT` in the above SQL fragment for consistency.

You can read more about `@DiscriminatorFormula` [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-single-table).

Comment: Here, i want to use either 'CREATOR' or 'USER' based on the check of the user type. I don't want to have the TANDC_TYPE as 'CREATOR' for both 'CREATOR' and 'USER'. Is that possible ?  Something like if(userType.equals("CREATOR") { db.setTandCType("CREATOR"); } else {db.setTandCType("USER"); }

Comment: If you want your code to influence that, I see no reason why you then just cannot extend `AccountTermsAndConditions` with a new discriminator value for `USER` with no additional fields then.

Comment: Thanks. Working !!